# I can't get the OnClick to work in visual composer with my Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmPLs.png)

I've tried a lot of different codes and one I've even found on here.

here is the most recent one: ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘Button’, ‘Click-E&O’, ‘Applied for E&O Coverage’, , {‘NonInteraction’: 1});"

and I tried the one from this post but can't get that to work either: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiV5uj0lt7VAhXHJiYKHdb6CAcQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F40191858%2Fonclick-event-tracking-google-analytics-wordpress-visual-composer-plugin&usg=AFQjCNF4QLr3Tlz291iu5FEg1CFQcxCqyw

Answer (score 0):

use the raw html block in visual composer editor to create your link and add the OnClick - otherwise in all other blocks the OnClick will be stripped from the code.